# couchbase insert and query latency

Tags: java, couchbase

I am writing some integration tests for an app I built that uses couchbase.

I am using Java. My question is, if I insert a document using:

```
bucket.insert(rawJsonDocument);
```

And then immediately run an [`N1qlQuery`](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.3.0/com/couchbase/client/java/query/N1qlQuery.html), should I expect to get a response when querying for the document that I just inserted, or is there some expected time period/delay before the document is actually persisted in the bucket?

I am seeing cases where my tests are failing intermittently because the document isn't being found, but I re-ran the test, and it works sporadically.

Does the couchbase bucket object have something similar to what an [`EntityManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) in JPA has with its flush operation? I know flush has a totally different meaning in couchbase, but I'm trying to nail down why I'm seeing this behavior.

I've verified the query syntax using the query tool in the console.

Comment: Eventual consistency means there is some delay, but the data lands in memory of a data node before fully persisted/replicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple consistency options you can choose from. Though you need to use them carefully and understand how it will impact your application performance.

Options are :

-Not bounded (default)

-RequestPlus - waits for all document changes and index updates

-AtPlus - allows 'read your own write'

You read discussion about them in this blog post. 
https://blog.couchbase.com/new-to-couchbase-4-5-atplus/

Comment: excellent. i believe this is exactly what i was looking for. thanks